# Problem installing aircrack-ng

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to install aircrack-ng by following the simple steps on the [official site](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack) which read

```
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1
make
make install
```

I executed the first three cmds successfully, however

```
make
```

returns

```
common.mak:100: *** Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl. install either libnl1 or libnl3..  Stop.
```

So I installed libnl1 with

```
sudo apt-get -y install libnl1
```

After this installed successfully, I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

However I still get the same error when calling **make**

```
common.mak:100: *** Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl. install either libnl1 or libnl3..  Stop.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

05/01/2016 WORKING

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential libsqlite3-dev iw wireless-tools
sudo apt-get install libnl1
wget https://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.3.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.3
autoreconf -i
./configure --with-experimental
make
make install
```

Notice that will some comments say that `./configure` is not needed, on the new version it's supported. Instructions [taken from oficial docs](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack&DokuWiki=052a66e6d52b9b09ca0ca5323023b108). Also check `INSTALLING` file on folder which may have more dependencies depending on your platform.

Comment: The tradition 3-phase build of a [tarball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) once it has been untarred is an incantation of "`./configure && make && sudo make install`"  - you seem to have missed the `./configure` stage (possible preceded with a `./configure --help` to see if there are any options or arguments to use for the particular project)...

Comment: Any explanation on what those commands do?

Comment: @SlySven `aircrack` doesn't need any configuration. Just compile and go. `./configure` is completely unnecessary. *It doesn't even exist in the first place.*

Comment: Ok, yeah, for this one that *is* the case... *\*sigh\**

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libnl1-dev
```

solved this issue

Answer (score -1):

apt-get install libnl-3-dev (on Kali debian distro) worked for me

Comment: What does this add above and beyond the original answer? It also read less like an answer and more like it worked for me.